# How to search multiple indices using elasticsearch hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

Suppose the following senario: We have following indices index-1,index-2,index-4, yes for some reason 'index-3' was missed, by I didn't know that during search time, so i'd like to search a index pattern like "index-1,index-2,index-3,index-4", in http request, i can set the option "ignore_unavailable" to ignore the missing indices.

But how can I achieve the same effect using "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat"? If I set [es.resource.read] to "index-1,index-2,index-3,index-4", job will fail with index not found exception. While set "es.index.read.missing.as.empty" to true, the result become empty, even if some of the indices in the index pattern exists.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug that should be filed on their [GH Page](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues)